# requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url

Tags: python, python-requests

Im working on pycharm flask and im trying to get similar news articles using: from googlesearch import search
and I also called all the necessary libraries like:

```
pip install google
pip install googlesearch-python
pip install search_google
```

My code in app.py:

```py
    news_title = article.title  # title of the article given by the user 
    similar = search(news_title, num_results=5)
```

but I'm getting an error:

```
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url:
```

See stack trace below.

````
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
        response = self.full_dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
        raise value
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
        rv = self.dispatch_request()
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
        return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\app.py", line 31, in send
        similar = search(news_title, num_results=5)
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py", line 29, in search
        html = fetch_results(term, num_results, lang)
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\googlesearch\__init__.py", line 16, in fetch_results
        response.raise_for_status()
      File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\flaskProject\venv\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 941, in raise_for_status
        raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
    requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url: https://www.google.com/sorry/index?continue=https://www.google.com/search%3Fq%3DFebruary%2B22,%2B2021%2BMerrick%2BGarland%2Bconfirmation%2Bhearing%26num%3D6%26hl%3Den&hl=en&q=EgTVr76lGLDW3oEGIhkA8aeDS8JiejR13ZuPCAsRa9kS_PJw4vRYMgFy ```


    127.0.0.1 - - [25/Feb/2021 15:50:40] "POST /send HTTP/1.1" 500 -
````

Comment: 429 mean's you're being rate limited by google. Check your code that you're not spamming then. If you really need to bypass it then you're going to need to start sending requests via a proxy or using distributed service so that your requests are spread out over different IPs

Comment: how can i do it any idea ?

Comment: im not spamming them im only searching for news

Comment: @ElioNajem You don't understand, Google's OWN servers will block your requests automatically if you do what you're doing here. They already told you: HTTP ERROR 429 means POST request limiting. What you need to do is figure out two things: REST api standards and how to perform the task at hand without getting rate limited, either place a Sleep on your Python code or look up how to avoid triggering that error on the Google servers when you're making requests because what you're doing is not going to hit their actual backend and perform the search.

Answer (score 2):

[429 Too Many Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/429) means that

> The HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response status code indicates the user
> has sent too many requests in a given amount of time ("rate
> limiting").
>
> A Retry-After header might be included to this response indicating how
> long to wait before making a new request.

You should limit number of queries in given amount time to avoid such situation.

Comment: i already did num_results = 5, i sent the project to my friend and it works normally, i don't know if the problem is with my pc

Answer (score 0):

i changed my IP address and it works now

Comment: That's because that's how you are identified.