# Cost Management API written in Python is returning a 429 error

Tags: python, azure

I have a Python program which queries the cost management API. This was working fine but then I started to get more and more  {"code":"429","message":"Too many requests. Please retry."} errors. Please advise what I should do? Could this be the result of limits set on the Resource Manager for the subscription/s. Should there be a  “Retry-after” in the Header? Please help.

Tried to wait or 'Sleep' for a minute.

Comment: You answered most of the question yourself. And about the header: you received the response, you can check for headers.

Answer (score 0):

The error is transient and occurs when We send multiple requests to the Cost management API, When I ran the code below, I got the desired output:-

**Code:-**

```py
import requests

import time

from azure.identity import  DefaultAzureCredential

from azure.mgmt.costmanagement import  CostManagementClient

  

def  main():

client = CostManagementClient(

credential=DefaultAzureCredential(),

)

  

response = client.query.usage(

scope="subscriptions/<subscription-id>",

parameters={

"dataset": {

"filter": {

"and": [

{

"or": [

{

"dimensions": {

"name": "ResourceLocation",

"operator": "In",

"values": ["East US", "West Europe", "UK South"],

}

},

{"tags": {"name": "Environment", "operator": "In", "values": ["UAT", "Prod"]}},

]

},

{"dimensions": {"name": "ResourceGroup", "operator": "In", "values": ["API"]}},

]

},

"granularity": "Daily",

},

"timeframe": "MonthToDate",

"type": "Usage",

},

)

print(response)

  
  

# x-ms-original-file: specification/cost-management/resource-manager/Microsoft.CostManagement/stable/2022-10-01/examples/BillingAccountQuery.json

if  __name__ == "__main__":

main()
```

[image]

When I ran the code again, I received the same error, as the back end server was not able to retrieve multiple requests at the same time, Refer below:-

[image]

I waited for 5-10 minutes and ran the code again, And received the desired output again:-

[image]

As an alternative you can directly call the API from the API management tool or Postman like below:-

[image]

**scope** = subscriptions/subscription-id

**Body** =

```json
{
  "type": "Usage",
  "timeframe": "MonthToDate",
  "dataset": {
    "granularity": "Daily",
    "filter": {
      "and": [
        {
          "or": [
            {
              "dimensions": {
                "name": "ResourceLocation",
                "operator": "In",
                "values": [
                  "East US",
                  "West Europe"
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "tags": {
                "name": "Environment",
                "operator": "In",
                "values": [
                  "UAT",
                  "Prod"
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "dimensions": {
            "name": "ResourceGroup",
            "operator": "In",
            "values": [
              "API"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:-**

You can check your Cost management  API rate limit quota in the output here and plan your header accordingly in the code, Refer below:-

[image]

```http
x-ms-ratelimit-microsoft.costmanagement-qpu-consumed: 1
x-ms-ratelimit-microsoft.costmanagement-qpu-remaining: QueriesPerHour:597,QueriesPerMin:58,QueriesPer10Sec:11
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-microsoft.costmanagement-clienttype-requests: DefaultQuota:2616
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-microsoft.costmanagement-entity-requests: DefaultQuota:2
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-microsoft.costmanagement-tenant-requests: DefaultQuota:18
x-ms-ratelimit-remaining-subscription-resource-requests: 98
```

**Output Response:-**

[image]

**References:-**

[Query - Usage - REST API (Azure Cost Management) | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cost-management/query/usage?tabs=HTTP&tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)

[python - requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 429 Client Error: Too Many Requests for url - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66370259/requests-exceptions-httperror-429-client-error-too-many-requests-for-url) By Daweo